# Replace each character with span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get some search string strings from an object `obj[item].coveredText` and want to replace every character of this search string with a span.

Actually, I'm only able to replace the entire search string with one span. Thank for your hints.

```
var rangeRoot = $("#plainText");

for (var item in obj) { 

    var input = rangeRoot.html();
    var str = obj[item].coveredText;

    var type = obj[item].type;
    var level = obj[item].level;
    var id = obj[item].id;

    var toReplace = str;

    var newSpan = '<span data-id="' + id + '" class="annotation level' + level + ' ' + type + '">' + str + '</span>';
    var regEx = new RegExp(toReplace, "g");
    var output = input.replace(regEx, newSpan);
    $(rangeRoot).empty();
    $(rangeRoot).append(output);

  };
```

**Example Input**

*This is an example of an text*

**Object**

```
       {
            "coveredText": "example",
            "type": "exampleType",
            "id": 4704,
            "level": 2
        }
```

**Output**

```
this is an <span data-id="4704" class="annotation level2 exampleType">e</span><span data-id="4704" class="annotation level2 exampleType">x</span><span data-id="4704" class="annotation level2 exampleType">a</span><span data-id="4704" class="annotation level2 exampleType">m</span>
```

...

Comment: I've added the example and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your original code pattern using regular expressions, you should specify a replacement function that uses `.replace` again to replace each character with that character surrounded by the HTML text:

```js
const input = `This is an example of an text`;
const obj = {
  "coveredText": "example",
  "type": "exampleType",
  "id": 4704,
  "level": 2
};
const { coveredText, type, id, level } = obj;
const pattern = new RegExp(coveredText, 'g');

const replacer = () => (
  coveredText.replace(/./g, char => (
    `<span data-id="${id}" class="annotation level${level} ${type}">${char}</span>`
  ))
);
const output = input.replace(pattern, replacer);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the coveredText into independent characters and create a character-span mapping

Then for each character in the input, use the mapping lookup to replace it with corresponding span.

Find code below.

You don't have to loop the keys with for..in since it is used to iterate through the individual keys and is not the required logic to copy values to the variables as needed in this case.

```js
var rangeRoot = $("#plainText");
    var input = rangeRoot.text();
    var obj = {
            "coveredText": "example",
            "type": "exampleType",
            "id": 4704,
            "level": 2
        }
    var str = obj.coveredText;
    var type = obj.type;
    var level = obj.level;
    var id = obj.id;

    var spanMap = str.split('').reduce((acc,char) => {
      if(!acc[char])
         acc[char] = `<span data-id="${id}" class="annotation level${level} ${type} "> ${char} </span>`;
      return acc;
      }, {}) 

    // console.log(spanMap); // see the mapping here;

    var output = input.split('').map(char => spanMap[char]? spanMap[char] : char).join('');
    $(rangeRoot).empty();
    $(rangeRoot).append(output);
```

```css
.level2 {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plainText"> Hello world </div>
```

Comment: thx Dhananjaj! Actually I get an issue for ...spanMap, what do you mean by this ...

Comment: @mm1975 it is just a character to span mapping. Like for example, it would be { e: `<span ... >e</span>`, b: `<span ...>b</span>} etc so that you can easily get corresponding span value for a character

Comment: @mm1975 fixed a typo. try now